# How to use math mode inside align*

Tags: math-mode, align

Why does this give an error?

```
\begin{align*}
    $\sum_{i=0}^K n_{\text{i}} * P *  1000$
\end{align*}
```

Why can't I use `align*` for my math formula which includes a summation?

Comment: Remove the dollar signs. `align` already enters math mode. The dollar signs are for inline math.

Comment: Additionally, if your summation index `i` is used in the further formula, it's still a variable and should not be set in `\text{i}` but just as `i`. In this case especially (for math) to distinguish the variable `i` from the complex unit `\text{i}` - or as i prefer even `\textrm{i}`.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the comments above, the `align` and `align*` environments need the `amsmath` package.  Here is a working example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{i=0}^K n_i * P *  1000
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

In most circumstances one would not use `*` for multiplatication, a blank is sufficient, or `\times` can be used instead for "emphasis".  Also, your example contains no alignment point, so probably the ams environment `equation*` (for a single line) or `gather*` (if there are multiple lines) would be more appropriate.

Comment: Or `\cdot` for those who are used to those kind of things... :)

Comment: @zeroth Yes, that's a good alternative.